Schema value generated by swagger
I use spring boot 3.3
@Data
public class LongEditorRequest extends ShortEditorRequest {
    @NotNull
    private BookLangEnum bookLangEnum;;
...
}


@Schema(enumAsRef = true)
public enum BookLangEnum {
   ...
}

LongEditorRequest is used in many endpoint
In swagger, in the schema section
BookLangEnum_General
BookLangEnum
I don't have any BookLangEnum_General created in the application, so I assume is generated by swagger
I have the same behaviour for other class
Any way to have only one object in the schema?
